# Is there a dynamic implementation of the Gap Method in Python?

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

I am looking for a dynamic implementation of the Gap Method, where I can vary the algorithm and distance measure. More specifically, for mixed data, I am required to use Gower's distances.

From what I know, the reference distribution should be uniform for the continuous features and discrete uniform for the categorical features.

https://datasciencelab.wordpress.com/2013/12/27/finding-the-k-in-k-means-clustering/

https://glowingpython.blogspot.com/2019/01/a-visual-introduction-to-gap-statistics.html

https://github.com/Mavengence/Pattern_Analysis_SS20_FAU/blob/master/Exercise_6.ipynb

I've attached a couple of links of various implementations, but am not sure how to adapt this to my case. What to do for clustering algorithms that do not rely on centroids or exemplars?